# FCM: Track status FCM push notification

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

How to track FCM push notification status? If it is delivered then to how many devices it has been delivered. I want add this statistics to my dashboard for tracking purpose.

Answer (score 2):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en
See here it is well explained about FCM statistics. You can add your app here and see status of sent notification.